# how can filter data of calender in c# according to room names?

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api

How can I filter my events of outlook according to room name?

```
var queryOptions1 = new List<QueryOption>()
{
  new QueryOption("startDateTime", starttimeluis ),
  new QueryOption("endDateTime", Endtimeluis)

};
var calendarView1 = await graphClient.Me.Calendar.CalendarView
                            .Request(queryOptions1)
                            .GetAsync();
```

I want to filter calendar event data according to room name, how to do a query in c#.net?

Comment: Do you have any more concern? Feel free to share.

Answer (score 1):

You could try following code snippet

```cs
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var findRooms = await graphClient.Me
    .FindRooms("Building2Rooms@YourOrganization.onmicrosoft.com")
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

As it is `Microsoft Graph beta version` so you have install `Microsoft.Graph.Beta package`. See the below screen shot

[image]

For more details please refer to [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-findrooms?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp)

***Update:***

You could [`$filter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter) your query like this format:

```
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$filter=ReceivedDateTime ge 2017-04-01 and receivedDateTime lt 2017-05-01");

            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IkFRQUJBQUFB");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            string output = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: can i filter events using  startdate,enddate and room name in one query

Comment: I haven't seen anything on SDK but on `HTTP` request allow `$filter` option [refer this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter) like this `$filter=start/dateTime ge '2017-07-01T08:00'`

Comment: how to do in c#.net , how to add start date end date and event name in one query ?

Comment: I would update my answer how to use filter option on `C#` but `FindRooms` doesn't allow `startDateTime`  and `endDateTime` `$filter option`